# Filter through Permutations

Tags: python, recursion, permutation

I'm coding a project and I've realized that when I try to do long permutations, my program just takes forever to run it. The good thing is that the only permutations that I need are the ones that start with and end with a '#'. Here's a function that I am using to collect permutations:

```
def permut(array):
    if len(array) == 1:
        return [array]
    res = []
    for permutation in permut(array[1:]):
        for i in range(len(array)):
            res.append(permutation[:i] + array[0:1] + permutation[i:])
    return res

permut('c#e#')
```

and the only permutations I would need would be if `array[0] = '#'` and `array[len(s)-1] = '#'`. I apologize if this is a similar question, but how would I filter through strings I do not need and make my code actually run and not take forever.

Comment: are there only ever 2 `#` characters in the input sequence?

Comment: If your constraints are that simple (if all strings have two '#' in them), you could remove them at the start, permute the rest, and add them back in to the front and back

Comment: What if there is only 1 `#`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take two `#` characters out of the input, generate permutations of what's left, and stick `#` characters on each end of the generated permutations. Note that it's quite likely that you'll *still* have far too many permutations to ever go through.

By the way, you don't need to write your own permutation generator. The standard library provides [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), which is substantially faster than your code and doesn't have a few of the bugs your code does.

```
import itertools
def hash_on_each_end_permutations(array):
    array = list(array)
    array.remove('#')
    array.remove('#')
    for subpermutation in itertools.permutations(array):
        yield '#' + ''.join(subpermutation) + '#'
```